# Last observation carried backward for NA values from adjacent columns for all consecutive NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

| Row_Num | Patient_ID | Start_Date | Start_Window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-04-01 |
| 2 | 001 | 2023-04-03 | NA |
| 3 | 001 | 2023-04-05 | NA |
| 4 | 001 | 2023-04-06 | NA |
| 5 | 001 | 2023-04-08 | NA |
| 6 | 001 | 2023-04-09 | 2023-04-09 |
| 7 | 001 | 2023-04-11 | 2023-04-11 |
| 8 | 001 | 2023-04-13 | NA |
| 9 | 001 | 2023-04-16 | NA |
| 10 | 001 | 2023-04-18 | 2023-04-18 |
| 11 | 002 | 2023-04-02 | 2023-04-02 |
| 12 | 002 | 2023-04-04 | 2023-04-04 |
| 13 | 002 | 2023-04-07 | 2023-04-07 |
| 14 | 002 | 2023-04-08 | 2023-04-08 |
| 15 | 002 | 2023-04-10 | NA |

```
# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(
  Row_Num = c(1:15),
  Patient_ID = c(rep(001, 10), rep(002, 5)),
  Start_Date = c("2023-04-01", "2023-04-03", "2023-04-05", "2023-04-06", "2023-04-08",
                 "2023-04-09", "2023-04-11", "2023-04-13", "2023-04-16", "2023-04-18",
                 "2023-04-02", "2023-04-04", "2023-04-07", "2023-04-08", "2023-04-10"),
  Start_Window = c("2023-04-01", NA, NA, NA, NA, "2023-04-09", "2023-04-11", NA, NA, "2023-04-18",
                   "2023-04-02", "2023-04-04", "2023-04-07", "2023-04-08", NA)
)

# Print the table
print(df)
```

I have the table above which is created using the reproducible R code above.

I want to replace the "NA" in start window with the value for "start date".
However, when the NA values are consecutive for each patient ID I want to carry the first value backwards.

So in this example, In row 1-5 start_window should be "2023-04-08".
In row 8-9 start_window should be "2023-04-16".
Row 15 should be "2023-04-10".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a grouping ID based on `Patient_ID` and the run length of `Start_Window` and for `NA`s take the last value of `Start_Date` by this group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(temp_id = consecutive_id(Start_Window, Patient_ID)) %>%
  mutate(Start_Window = if_else(is.na(Start_Window), last(Start_Date), Start_Window),
         temp_id = NULL, .by = temp_id)

   Row_Num Patient_ID Start_Date Start_Window
1        1          1 2023-04-01   2023-04-01
2        2          1 2023-04-03   2023-04-08
3        3          1 2023-04-05   2023-04-08
4        4          1 2023-04-06   2023-04-08
5        5          1 2023-04-08   2023-04-08
6        6          1 2023-04-09   2023-04-09
7        7          1 2023-04-11   2023-04-11
8        8          1 2023-04-13   2023-04-16
9        9          1 2023-04-16   2023-04-16
10      10          1 2023-04-18   2023-04-18
11      11          2 2023-04-02   2023-04-02
12      12          2 2023-04-04   2023-04-04
13      13          2 2023-04-07   2023-04-07
14      14          2 2023-04-08   2023-04-08
15      15          2 2023-04-10   2023-04-10
```